# Why doesn't '$.each' seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

When I have the following inside the same HTML document it seems to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
datasets[0] = {
    "buildnames": {
        label: "buildnames",
        data: ["test2-a1", "test2-a2", "test2-a3",  "test2-a4","test2-a5", "test2-a6"]
    }
};

function doSomething() {
    var i = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < datasets.length; j++){
        $.each(datasets[j], function(key, val) {
            val.color = i;
            ++i;
        });

        var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
        //var testkey = new RegExp("cover");
        $.each(datasets[j], function(key, val) {
            if (key.indexOf("failed") > -1 || key.indexOf("cover") > -1) {
                choiceContainer.append('<br /><input type="checkbox" name="' + key +
                '" checked="checked" id="id' + key + '">' +
                '<label for="id' + key + '">'
                + val.label + '</label>');
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

But when I'm exporting this to a separate JavaScript file and then importing it and call the function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="root/include/graph_1.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:doSomething()">doSomething</a>
```

I get the following error: '`$`' is undefined  and points at "`$.each(..`"
So why can't I use this function is I "export" all JavaScript code in an HTML document to another separate JavaScript file?

******************edit****************************************************************

I tried the tips below  and changed the order

@idbentley I did what you said and changed the order of those 2 so it is

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="root/include/graph_1.js"></script>
```

But now I get another error "Exception thrown and not caught" Anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Are you including your jquery script file above the include you have listed?

Comment: is your `<script />` tag for jquery before or after this?

Comment: Start the debugger/firebird/devtools and catch the Exception, this way you can provide us with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell with just hwat you gave us, but it sounds like you aren't including jQuery, or that you are loading jQuery after your script.

Comment: I did what you said and changed the order of those 2 so it is

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.flot.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="root/include/jquery.flot.crosshair.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="root/include/graph_1.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JQuery library BEFORE you include any of your own scripts.